# Something like scanner for binary data

Tags: java

Is there anything like scanner for binary data? I'd like for example to use delimiter like "\r\n" and get byte[] every time I invoke some method. Can u supply me with class which can do miracles like that?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html):

```
File file = new File("binaryFile.dat");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

byte[] array1 = ...
byte[] array2 = ...
byte[] array3 = ...

dos.writeInt(array1.length);
for(byte b : array1) dos.wrtieByte(b);

dos.writeInt(array2.length);
for(byte b : array2) dos.wrtieByte(b);

dos.writeInt(array3.length);
for(byte b : array3) dos.wrtieByte(b);
```

and read it like:

```
File file = new File("binaryFile.dat");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

byte[] array1 = new byte[dis.readInt()];
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) array1[i] = dis.readByte();

byte[] array2 = new byte[dis.readInt()];
for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) array2[i] = dis.readByte();

byte[] array3 = new byte[dis.readInt()];
for(int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) array3[i] = dis.readByte();
```

Answer (score 0):

Jakarta commons has a library you can use. Just download the .jar from [jakarta](http://jakarta.apache.org/) and download their .jar and add that to your build path via add external jars. `IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)`

Comment: but I'd like to get for example whole line of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [java.io.InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) class:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("your_file");
byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];  //reads how much bytes are readable from file
is.read(b);//reads the file and save all read bytes into b
```

Hope this helps